# How to web deploy from Visual Studio 2013 to Godaddy.com

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, shared-hosting

I am looking for help with the Web Deploy tool in Visual Studio for Web 2013 using godaddy.com as the host provider. I bought hosting space and linked a domain name to that hosting space.

I have a web forms solution I created in Visual Studio for Web 2013 and would like to now use the web deploy tool to deploy my ASP.NET website to this hosting space for the whole world wide web to see. This solution also has a small database, which I would also like to create on that hosting space.

What I am confused about is what exactly to enter in the fields of the Server, Site name, and Destination URL in the web deploy tool.

[image]

Imagine that my website is called 'awesomewebsite.com' and my username is 'awesomedude', what should I enter into those fields above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem by going into Websites and Domains in godaddy and there is an option to download the web deploy file. You just then import the profile on the Web Publish screen as shown above in my question and it works! So you don't have to fill out all the fields yourself, godaddy does it for you.

Comment: What is the user name and the password should be use.

Comment: where can I find the Websites and Domains settings in godaddy? I can't it in my account.

Comment: @juniordeveloper look at the image in my question where it says "Websites and domains"

Comment: got it, turns out I need to have the Windows plan to have this feature.

Answer (score 17):

Question  #1:

Go to: 
[image: "Web Sites and Domains"]

[image: Web Deploy Publishing Settings]

[image: Import deployment settings]

[image: Complete with your plesk admin password]

Thats it!

Comment: For the benefit of others, apparently we need a "Windows Hosting with Plesk" account to do this. I have a "Classic Hosting Windows" account and I do not have a "Web Deploy Publishing Settings" anywhere. GoDaddy's instructions indicate we need to use Plesk for that.

Comment: Did anyone get this to work with a virtual directory in godaddy? I get a permission issue while trying to add the subfolder.

Comment: I have been successful at doing this once for each of two domains. After the first time I always get the certificate error. Also note that when I do this for Azure, both the user name and the password are provided with the downloaded profile but GoDaddy does not provide the password. I have asked GoDaddy many times in many ways for a solution but they just don't care about developers using shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Additional Information:

If you receive an ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED error after adding the publish file there is an easy fix for this:

Edit the settings of the publish that you added by clicking "Settings..." in the summary.  Once you hit the publish screen just hit validate connection, this will prompt you to add the certificate.